# How can I make getevent/sendevent work inside android application?

Tags: android, shell, automation, adb

I know there is a tool called **ADB** which has **SHELL** commands **getevent** and **sendevent** for getting/sending device's touch/key event. However, it just works through connecting android device to pc.

So I want to know if there is an **existing library** that allow us to use such functions **inside an android application**? Or would there be alternatives do similar stuffs?

I would like to have something like this application https://code.google.com/p/android-event-injector/
It can sendevent to your device without using ADB and no need to connect to pc. It seems not a flexible library for send/get event, but just an app which is not what I want.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27603

Comment: @Sreekanthss I've looked those articles list in your link.Those articles just explain how to use getevent/sendevent command, but no use in making those functions work inside android apps.

Comment: you linked the project which comes with sources for both the app and the lib. if you are unable to use that - I doubt we can help

Comment: Finally, I get it done by extract and modify part of code from the above application project https://code.google.com/p/android-event-injector/. Thanks for your help.